# How to use DictationServices.framework

Tags: objective-c, private, dictating

Mac 10.8 contains the private DictationServices.framework

It would never get approved in the App Store but just out of interest:
How could one make use of its private classes, methods and messages?

```
root:~/DictationServices.framework$ strings DictationServices
```

reveals the following:

- SOMicrophonePopUpButton SOMicrophoneView
  SOMicrophoneLevelMeterController SOEnableDictationPanelController
  SODictationHotKeyController SOEnableDictationDelegate

  logDictationFinished:serverError:

  com.apple.message.dictationstatus
  com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using class dump to extract the header files? It should just be a matter of including those headers in your project and linking to the framework.

Comment: thanks, class-dump is much nicer than otool -fahlLDtdorSTMRIHvVcXm ;}

Comment: nice, that gives all the methods in @interface SODictationPreferences ... however getting access to an instance of SODictationPreferences is probably not trivial.(?) Follow up question: How to set gdb breakpoints on private interface methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703385/how-to-set-gdb-breakpoints-on-private-interface-methods