# How to set gdb breakpoints on private interface methods

Tags: objective-c, gdb

Lets say Apple uses a private framework DictationServices.framework which has an @interface SODictationPreferences with symbol/method dictationEnabled. How would one be able to **programmatically** set a breakpoint on that method (With ObjectiveC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly via ptrace?

```
 ptrace -- process tracing and debugging
```

SYNOPSIS
     #include 
     #include

```
 int
 ptrace(int request, pid_t pid, caddr_t addr, int data);
```

DESCRIPTION
     ptrace() provides tracing and debugging facilities.  It allows one process (the tracing process) to control another (the traced process).

Comment: For the lack of a better answer I will accept this.

Comment: Apparently you somehow need to find out where target method resides, and then modify the process in order to insert a debugging method call.
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6210

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it non-programmatically:

```
root:~/DictationServices.framework$ ps -Afw | grep Preferences
  501 44726 44621   0  7:46PM ??         0:02.60 /Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System Preferences
// pid of /Applications/System Preferences.app == 44726 
(gdb) attach 44726 
Attaching to process 44726.
Reading symbols for shared libraries + done
Reading symbols for shared libraries +++.+.+.+.+++++++..+++++++ done
Reading symbols for shared libraries + done
0x00007fff8befe686 in mach_msg_trap ()
(gdb) b dictationEnabled
Breakpoint 3 at 0x10e57bc93
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Breakpoint 3, 0x000000010e57bc93 in -[SODictationPreferences dictationEnabled] ()
(gdb)
```