# Can I use OS X 10.8's speech recognition/dictation without a GUI?

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, speech-recognition, osx-mountain-lion

Ideally I would like to use 10.8's/Mountain Lion's dictation feature from Python, without a GUI.  As far as I can tell dictation is currently only supported by using the [UITextInput protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput), which implies a GUI (correct?).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you tagged this under python? Are you looking to with it in python?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my question, ideally I would like to use the dictation feature from within Python.

Comment: Oh my bad I admit to skimming...

Comment: You might also want to follow this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702804/how-to-use-dictationservices-framework

Comment: I'm pretty sure `UITextInput` is how you use iOS's dictation feature from iOS, and has nothing to do with OS X, so you've been searching in the wrong place.

Comment: June 2015 -- Bump! Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Sorry to say I did not.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dummy text field and programmatically start dictating by emulating the keypress (tried out successfully here)

Comment: @Anno2001 Can you give me a hint how to emulate the "fn" key press twice?

Comment: ```CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x3F, true)``` it is :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech). `SFSpeechRecognizer` et al. I don't believe this requires a window session on macOS as this is part of `AVFoundation`, though I'm not 100% certain. Try it and see. :-)